# Cannot login after removing password from user account

Tags: login, password

So I removed the password of my user account and restarted. When I tried to login, a black screen showed up and took me immediately back to the login screen. Running Ubuntu 11.04 via LiveCD, I found the /home folder is owned by root, no idea if it has to do with that. I also checked the option to encrypt the user folder at installation, propably wasn't the best idea.

I can login with ctrl + alt + f1, when I then try to start x, it gives me the error message, that .Xauthority is missing. Now I wonder how I'd create that file, when I can't access my /home/user folder, because it is encrypted. It also tells me on login that I should run encryptfs-mount-private.

Answer (score 1):

When you encrypted your user folder, you used the Ecryptfs program. Ecryptfs actually uses two different passwords to encrypt this folder. When you removed your login password, you needed to also change your Ecryptfs password. This protection exists to prevent root from tampering with the password of your encrypted directory. If you want to read more about Ubuntu and encryption, check out:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHomeDirectoryHowto

The problem with .Xauthority was likely caused by this Ecryptfs lockout. Try these suggestions, and reply if the .Xauthority problem isn't fixed by solving the lockout problem.

1. To change the Ecryptfs password, try:

   ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase

   For more information, visit:

   http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-change-ecryptfs-home-cripted-filesystem-password-on-ubuntu-and-get-your-files-back/
2. The Ecryptfs tutorial is also very helpful. If you remember your Ecryptfs password, you may be able to use that live CD to access your directory using chroot:

   http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/Ecryptfs